# How to purge missing values from a DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

After reading the context, if you felt the title could be enhanced to fit the question and you had an idea, feel free to update it.
Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(
  g=["a","b","a","c",missing,missing,missing,missing],
  a=[1,2,3,4,missing,missing,missing,missing],
  Column1=[missing,missing,missing,missing,false,false,false,true],
  Column2=[missing,missing,missing,missing,false,true,true,true],
  Column3=[missing,missing,missing,missing,true,true,false,false],
)
# 8×5 DataFrame
#  Row │ g        a        Column1  Column2  Column3
#      │ String?  Int64?   Bool?    Bool?    Bool?
# ─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────
#    1 │ a              1  missing  missing  missing
#    2 │ b              2  missing  missing  missing
#    3 │ a              3  missing  missing  missing
#    4 │ c              4  missing  missing  missing
#    5 │ missing  missing    false    false     true
#    6 │ missing  missing    false     true     true
#    7 │ missing  missing    false     true    false
#    8 │ missing  missing     true     true    false
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
# 8×5 DataFrame
#  Row │ g        a        Column1  Column2  Column3
#      │ String?  Int64?   Bool?    Bool?    Bool?
# ─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────
#    1 │ a              1    false    false     true
#    2 │ b              2    false     true     true
#    3 │ a              3    false     true    false
#    4 │ c              4     true     true    false
```

I tried:

```
DataFrame(collect.(skipmissing.(eachcol(df))), names(df))
```

But I think this is not an optimal way since I'm using the `collect` function. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me a natural way to do it would be:

```
julia> mapcols(x -> filter(!ismissing, x), df)
4×5 DataFrame
 Row │ g        a       Column1  Column2  Column3
     │ String?  Int64?  Bool?    Bool?    Bool?
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ a             1    false    false     true
   2 │ b             2    false     true     true
   3 │ a             3    false     true    false
   4 │ c             4     true     true    false
```

However, this assumes that number of missing values in every column is the same (but I guess this is what you have in this exercise - right?).

`skipmissing` is designed for cases when user wants a non-copying iterable skipping `missing` values (which is not the case here).

Comment: Exactly professor, each column should have the same count of missing values. This situation can happen when someone uses `append!` with `cols=:union` (if I remember the exact case correctly.) Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes `append!` can produce such a result assuming each data frame you `append!` has the same number of rows and they do not have common columns. However, then probably using `hcat` is better.

Comment: Exactly. First, I tried the `hcat` but since I was writing operations in a function and planned to mutate the input `df,` I couldn't manage to mutate it in place using `hcat`, and that led to using `append!`. I think it's better to ask another question about mutating the input DataFrame within a function in place using `hcat`. (I don't know if that procedure is possible)

Comment: use `insertcols!` instead.